OpenAPI codegen gradle plugin ignores failOnUnknownProperties
I have this configuration in my build.gradle.kts file
tasks.register<org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask>("openApiGenerateSamApi") {
    generatorName.set("kotlin")
    inputSpec.set("src/main/resources/sam-1.0-patched.yml")
    outputDir.set(samOpenApiGenerateOutputDir)
    modelPackage.set("ch.srg.sam.generated.model")
    modelNameSuffix.set("Dto")
    generateModelDocumentation.set(false)
    configOptions.set(
        mapOf(
            Pair("dateLibrary", "java8"),
            Pair("serializationLibrary", "jackson"),
            Pair("enumPropertyNaming", "UPPERCASE"),
            Pair("failOnUnknownProperties", "false"),
        ),
    )
}
tasks.getByName("openApiGenerateSamApi").dependsOn("kspKotlin")

However the generated serializer does not include DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES:
object Serializer {
    @JvmStatic
    val jacksonObjectMapper: ObjectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
        .findAndRegisterModules()
        .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
        .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
}

Even if I set failOnUnknownProperties to true there is no effect.
Problem is, that the client is useless as soon as the service adds a field to their domain model

In the end I just use the standard serializationLibrary which is GSON. With it there are no problems with unknownProperties.
configOptions.set(
    mapOf(
        Pair("dateLibrary", "java8"),
        Pair("enumPropertyNaming", "UPPERCASE"),
    ),
)

